# How to make 2 window event listener in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

i want to run a function when the arrowdown button is pressed &un a function again if the arrowdown button isn't pressed.

```
const Gamefile = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
     if(e.key === 'ArrowDown'){
        duck();
    }
     }
   
     )
    window.addEventListener('keyup'), e => {
        if(e.key === 'ArrowDown'){
            notduck();
        }
    }
    })
}
```

i tried this code but it's error, "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions"

Answer (score 0):

Second `addEventListener` is wrong. You are passing just one argument, the listener function is not passed.

```
const Gamefile = () => {
        useEffect(() => {
            window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
                if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                    duck();
                }
            });
            window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
                if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                    notduck();
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

Also, I would recommend you add a cleanup function for this hook to remove listeners when they are not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake, you accidentally closed your bracket too early, so you weren't passing in the function.

```
const Gamefile = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                duck();
            }
        })
      
        window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
            if (e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                notduck();
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I would also personally recommend switching the key-tracking over to a hook. I wrote a quick hook that handles this, and cleans up the events as well.

```
const useButtons = () => {
  const [pushed, setPushed] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePress = (event) => {
      setPushed((previous) => {
        return [...new Set([...previous, event.keyCode])];
      });
    };

    const handleUnpress = (event) => {
      setPushed((previous) => {
        return previous.filter((key) => event.keyCode !== key);
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handlePress);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleUnpress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handlePress);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleUnpress);
    };
  });

  return { pushed };
};
```

This really cleans up the usage, which looks as follows.

```
const App = () => {
  const { pushed } = useButtons();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Pushed Buttons</h1>
      <code>{pushed.toString()}</code>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```